# Add-ons are linking incorrectly in control panel

Tags: add-on, control-panel, url, addons

I've taken over a site created in EE and transferred it to my host. Since doing so, the addon tabs are linking incorrectly. What I mean is that on click it sends the admin to:

```
index.php?S=b84310dd48d074edf67c8d6c44848df407c64147&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=structure
```

Rather than sending the admin to

```
admin.php?S=b84310dd48d074edf67c8d6c44848df407c64147&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=structure
```

All default admin area links work fine, it is just Structure and rEEservation that have this problem.

How can I insure they link to the correct url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two comments below are worthy answers, however the fault was all mine.

I normally work with a boilerplate which has the control panel at {site_url}/admin.php . I forgot that some people don't have it set up that way.

The weird thing was that logging at {site_url}/admin.php worked until I tried to access add-ons, however logging in at {site_url}/system fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `$config['cp_url']`, under **Admin → System Administration → Config File Editor**. My guess would be that you have `index.php` as the script name in there.

Comment: or `/system/index.php`

Comment: I answered my own question, just a weird situation. Thanks for your answer, it is definitely one of the first places to check.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the shortcut tabs and it'll be fine.